# Milliseconds for current date in javascript

Tags: javascript, date

When I try the following

```
new Date().valueOf()
```

the result is 140082670954. For

```
new Date('05/23/2014').valueOf()
```

the result is 1400783400000.

There is a difference in the millisecond outputs. The second one is at 00:00:00 hrs but the first one is at 12pm with todays date.

I need to get the milliseconds as in the second one. How would I do this dynamically?

Answer (score 1):

When you do:

```
new Date()
```

a new Date object is created with a time value for the current instant. When you do:

```
new Date('05/23/2014')
```

a new Date object is created at 00:00:00.000 on the specified date. If you want the equivalent using the constructor, then create the Date and set the time appropriately:

```
var d = new Date();
d.setHours(0,0,0,0);
```

#### NB

Please don't pass strings to the Date constructor. It calls [*Date.parse*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.4.2) which is largely implementation dependent and inconsistent across browsers (even using the [*string format specified in ES5*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.1.15)). Call the constructor with the required values:

```
new Date(2014, 4, 23);
```

noting that months are zero indexed so May is `4`.

Answer (score 0):

I take it that you want the milliseconds from midnight of a given day? I am afraid it won't be too simple, thanks to JavaScript's very constrained date-time API. You can extract the year, month, and day from the date object and create a new object from those:

```
var now = new Date();
var day = now.getDate();
var month = now.getMonth();
var year = now.getFullYear();

var today = new Date(year, month, day);

var millis = today.valueOf();
```

BTW: You mention that the first one "is at 12pm" - that depends on at what time you execute the statement. `new Date()` gives you the date including the current local time. So it appears that you tried it at roughly 12pm :-)